# tab_group_code field in the eav_attribute_group table

Tags: magento2, attribute-group

in the table `eav_attribute_group` there is a column called `tab_group_code` that has the values `null`, `basic`, `advanced`.
What is this column used for and how does the value influence the product add/edit page in admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Magento start development of 2 version on Product Page was different design with two group of tabs: Basic Setting and  Advanced Setting. See image. So field previously define in with of group show the tab  and now does not used
[image]

Comment: So is this used in later versions? Like 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: It exists in blocks but only in deprecated. So, looks like no